# eCommerce solution doesn't want to display its shortcodes or any content where it's set to

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm running the latest WordPress, WooCommerce; WC claims in its System Status that everything is okay. I tried disabling EVERY other plugin, changing themes, clearing my cache, having the permalink set to default (and then changing them to /shop/) and reinstalling WooCommerce.

Please, someone, before I throw this brick at my monitor.

I appreciate it.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Third party plugins are off-topic, see [help/on-topic]. Try the support forums at [WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce), or [WooThemes](http://support.woothemes.com).

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce has it's own loop (eg this is their ["Products Loop"](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/sample-products-loop/) that it loves to use, your theme may not support it and/or conflict with it. One way to rule this out is to use their themes (I know, shock, horror) fortunately they have some [free themes](http://www.woothemes.com/product-category/themes/free-themes/) you can use, if only for testing purposes.

Comment: Joshua, please [read this meta post](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3921/should-one-answer-a-borderline-off-topic-question) before you invest time in answering questions that get closed. Thanks.